STM32H745 sometimes crashes when setting the system clock speed to 480MHz
As the title reads I have a STM32H745 on custom hardware and when I run the following code the device crashes about 50% of the time at some point after switching the system clock to PLL1. By "crashes" I mean it becomes completely unresponsive, no hard fault handler or anything. It will appear to have stopped running and when I try to restart or pause the debug session it does this -

If I run the code on the STMH745-DISCO board it works 100% of the time. If I lower the clock speed to 240MHz it works 100% of the time on my hardware. Does this sound like an issue with my hardware? I've posted my code below as well.
void rcc_main_clock_config()
{
/*Divide the HSI (64MHz) by 8 so sys_clk = 8MHz*/
RCC->CR |=  RCC_CR_HSIDIV_8;

/*Initialize the PLL to accept 8MHz HSI.*/
/*Set the PLL1 CLK source to the HSI and divide by 1 so PLL in = 8MHz.*/
RCC->PLLCKSELR = RCC_PLLCKSELR_PLLSRC_HSI;

/*Set the all PLL refclk to 8MHz-16MHz range.*/
RCC->PLLCFGR |= RCC_PLLCFGR_PLL1RGE_3
            | RCC_PLLCFGR_PLL2RGE_3
            | RCC_PLLCFGR_PLL3RGE_3;

/*Initialize all 3 PLLs.*/
rcc_init_pll1();
rcc_init_pll2();
rcc_init_pll3();

/*Enable PLL1P for the sys_clk.*/
rcc_enable_pll1p();

/*Set domain 1 prescalers.*/
RCC->D1CFGR = RCC_D1CFGR_HPRE_DIV2
            | RCC_D1CFGR_D1CPRE_DIV1
            | RCC_D1CFGR_D1PPRE_DIV2;

/*Set domain 2 prescalers.*/
RCC->D2CFGR = RCC_D2CFGR_D2PPRE1_DIV2
            | RCC_D2CFGR_D2PPRE2_DIV2;

/*Set domain 3 prescalers.*/
RCC->D3CFGR = RCC_D3CFGR_D3PPRE_DIV2;


/*Set the sys_clk source to PLL1.*/
RCC->CFGR |= RCC_CFGR_SW_PLL1;

/*Wait until the clock has successfully switched.*/
while ((RCC->CFGR & RCC_CFGR_SWS_PLL1) == 0) {}
/********** CRASHES AT VARIOUS PLACES AFTER THIS POINT **********/
}



/*Initialize PLL1 to 480MHz.*/
 static void rcc_init_pll1()
 {
/*Set the initial divider to 1.*/
RCC->PLLCKSELR |= 1 << RCC_PLLCKSELR_DIVM1_Pos;

/*Multiply by 59 + 1, so this gives 8 * 60  = 480.*/
RCC->PLL1DIVR = (59 << RCC_PLL1DIVR_N1_Pos)     //Mult 60..
            | (1 << RCC_PLL1DIVR_R1_Pos)        //Div 2,    R = 240MHz
            | (0 << RCC_PLL1DIVR_Q1_Pos)        //No Div,   Q = 480MHz
            | (0 << RCC_PLL1DIVR_P1_Pos);       //No div,   P = 480MHz

/*Enable PLL1.*/
RCC->CR |= RCC_CR_PLL1ON;
while ((RCC->CR & RCC_CR_PLL1RDY) == 0){}
}



/*Initialize PLL2.*/
static void rcc_init_pll2()
{
/*Set the initial divider to 1.*/
RCC->PLLCKSELR |= 1 << RCC_PLLCKSELR_DIVM2_Pos;

/*Multiply by 28 + 1, so this gives 8 * 29  = 232.*/
RCC->PLL2DIVR = (24 << RCC_PLL2DIVR_N2_Pos)     //Mult 29..
            | (3 << RCC_PLL2DIVR_R2_Pos)        //Div 3,    R = 77.3333MHz
            | (0 << RCC_PLL2DIVR_Q2_Pos)        //No Div,   Q = 232MHz
            | (0 << RCC_PLL2DIVR_P2_Pos);       //No div,   P = 232MHz

/*Enable PLL1.*/
RCC->CR |= RCC_CR_PLL2ON;
while ((RCC->CR & RCC_CR_PLL2RDY) == 0){}
}



static void rcc_init_pll3()
{
/*Set the initial divider to 1.*/
RCC->PLLCKSELR |= 1 << RCC_PLLCKSELR_DIVM3_Pos;

/*Set up the dividers.*/
RCC->PLL3DIVR = (26 << RCC_PLL3DIVR_N3_Pos)     //Mult 27...
            | (17 << RCC_PLL3DIVR_R3_Pos)       //Div 18,   R = 12MHz
            | (0 << RCC_PLL3DIVR_Q3_Pos)        //No div,   Q = 216MHz
            | (0 << RCC_PLL3DIVR_P3_Pos);       //No div,   P = 216MHz

/*Enable PLL3.*/
RCC->CR |= RCC_CR_PLL3ON;
while ((RCC->CR & RCC_CR_PLL3RDY) == 0) {}
}


Layout, power supply or decoupling issue?

@winny I'm thinking probably layout and/or decoupling... Power supply is pretty robust. What sort of things should I be looking for on the layout/decoupling side of things? I, of course, have a decoupling cap close to each power pin of the MCU (0.1uF) and 2 2.2uF caps on the VCAP pins as specified in the datasheet(I'm using the internal LDO).

Show us a Pic of your layout around the MCU.

You are initializing the clock tree incorrectly.
The HSI is 64 MHz. The HSIPRE divider does affect the PLL reference input.
The 8 MHz HSI fed directly to PLL subsystem if used as a PLL clock source, so you are assuming the PLL input is 8 MHz.
Thus DIVM setting of 1 is OK.
However the next bits go wrong.
The PLL output postdividers also can't be 0 or 1. 0 is not allowed, and 1 will divide by 2.
Which means, you need to multiply by 120, not by 60. Then postdivide P by 2.
HPRE needs to be 2, as it is 240 MHz max.
D1PPRE, D2PPRE1, D2PPRE2 and D3PPRE must be 2 as they are 120 MHz max.

I'm seeing that the only PLL output post divider that can't be 0 is PLL1 DIVR (which I have set to 1). The rest can and a register value of 0 divides by 1.

@AlexJegers OK the reference manual allows different values than CubeMX tool then, so you are correct. However CubeMX wants to postdivide PLL1P by 2 before using it as sysclk. There might be reasons why it does that.

The problem you describe sounds very similar to what will happen when you have the incorrect flash wait state settings when changing the system clock. It's a software problem.
Basically flash memory is slow to access. At high system clock speeds, the flash simply won't keep up with the CPU. Therefore something called wait states are used - basically a setting telling the CPU to not run ahead but to wait for the flash to keep up.
The normal state of affairs when you have wrong wait state settings is that the program just crashes and becomes completely unresponsive, due to the CPU reading gibberish instructions from flash. It probably jumps to some hardware exception handler but those too are usually executed from flash, so... boom, dead.
Mid- to high-end CPUs can compensate for flash slowness by utilizing instruction- and data cache, reading the flash in advance before executing what's read from it. Therefore the program can perhaps work sporadically even with wrong wait states.
I don't remember how to set those on STM32 specifically, very brief research suggests there's a register VOS0 and an application note you should look into: https://community.st.com/t5/stm32-mcus-products/what-are-the-correct-values-for-embedded-flash-wait-state/td-p/265669

Thanks. I'm pretty sure that the default wait state value is set to the maximum but I will double check.
